Serverless deploy fails due to no such file "core-cloudformation-template.json"
I'm trying to deploy an AWS infastructure using serverless framework. When executed the deploy command it returns ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/node/.serverless/releases/4.1.6/package/lib/plugins/aws/package/lib/core-cloudformation-template.json'.
The techstack is Serverless Framework 4.1.6, Nodejs20
Full Debug Log


Did you fix that?

@ulou I couldnt find a proper solution. So, downgraded serverless to v3 and it worked as a temporary solution.

Not the best solution but I faced the same problem on my new laptop so I checked the serverless version on my old laptop and downgraded to that:
Serverless version 4.0.24 works for me while 4.1.7 throws an error identical  to the one OP has posted.
